# How to tell if a user's email already exists using the account-password package

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a registered user in my app, for example: *test@live.com*. While the user is typing the email address to login I want to check if the user exists on every key press and display a message.

I have written the following code:

```
Template.login.events({
    'keyup .userEmail': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var email=$('[name=email]').val();
        var checkExistence=Meteor.users.find({ emails: { $elemMatch: { address: email } }}).count() > 0 ;
        console.log(checkExistence);
    }
});
```

The query should return true if the email address exists.

When the user has written their complete email address that is *test@live.com* (which exists in the database), `checkExistence` should be true but its value is still false.

Why is this happening? How can I tell if the user's email is already in the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is most likely because the client does not have all of the data it requires in order to answer this question (nor should it). This is better implemented as a method (which is asynchronous).

Sending all of the users' emails to the user is not desired both as an unnecessary overhead that wastes server resources and bandwidth and as a security/privacy issue.

One way to tackle this is to add a reactive variable to the template, which represents the verification status. When the callback returns, it can check if the email being verified is still the one that is typed in the text box and change the status accordingly.

You should probably also throttle the event handling and validate the email prior to inquiring it.

In addition, note that `event.target` in your event handling method contains the element that is specified by the selector in the object key supplied to `events()`.